# IP filtering not working “Trial License” Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am using trial License to try the IP filtering, but it's not working.

[image]

I added this configuration to my elasticsearch.yml file:

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: full
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: "MASTER.key"
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: "MASTER.crt"
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: [ "ca.crt" ]

#===============Encryption between Elastic and kibana================
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: "http.p12"
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: "http.p12"


#================= Test audit and IP filtering ====================
xpack.security.audit.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.filter.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.filter.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.filter.deny: _all
xpack.security.transport.filter: _all
```

II tried to deny my IP address and it didn't work, so I decided to try to deny everything and didn't work too.
and for the auditing, I am not seeing any *_audit.json file !

Could you tell me please if the IP filetring don't work with Trial License, or I am doing something wrong in my configuration !

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure `xpack.security.transport.filter:` is valid (without `allow`, `deny`, or `enable`)? Also can you show how you are connecting to the cluster and ideally the relevant output in the logs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @xraa, I updated the question as the "audit" was working and it was just a mistake from me. However, the IP filtering is not working yet.
can you explain please what do you mean by saying "if the xpack.Security.transport.filter" is valid ? and how can I know that ! and for the logs I am not getting anything which has a relation with IP filetering, everything is okay

Comment: If I undestand well, when we deny everthing it means I can't connect to Kibana or even if I connect I can't search data ! but for me even when I deny everything I access Kibana and data without any problem

Comment: I see that you changed it to `xpack.security.transport.filter.enabled:`, so that should be better now. For allowing Kibana access: The idea is to add an allow rule for Kibana (which takes precedence over the global deny). But let's see why the global deny is not working. Can you show a curl request to the cluster and also the relevant logs from when the server is starting up?

Comment: The "xpack.security.http.filter" do not work for free. I use the iptables instead.